# Why isn't there an Apple Photos tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I see that the main site has an Apple Aperture tag, but this macOS software is obsolete. Apple has replaced it with the newer Photos app.

Is there a reason that there is not an Apple Photos tag yet? If not, can one be created please? As a Photos user, I'm not sure how to best tag my posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean, I see one... (j/k I just created it for you.)

Answer (score 2):

The main reason was that no one had yet created one. This site, like all of the stack exchange network, is made up of user created content.

If you see a need for something that isn't here, feel free to create it if you have the needed reputation.

Comment: Unless there's been an undocumented change, there's no review like there is for edits. You have to have 300 rep, and once you do, you can create all the tags you like. https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags